# Get and post in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

In Codeigniter I do this

```
$p=$this->input->post();
```

to get all objects posted but I don't know if there is something similar in cakephp to get all posted variables from a form ? I am writing a function to get posted password and save it into database in place of the old password recorded there.

I use native php to get 'posted' variables from a form, (I am not familiar with cakephp form usage) that is why, so instead of using $_POST['sssss'] what should I do now ?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 14):

```
$value = $this->request->data('key');
```

Please for further reference, read the manual. It's so much easier and better for yourself to figure it out by yourself.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-post-data

Comment: This is wrong, data is an array. $value = $this->request->data['key']; would be right.

Comment: Please read the manual, it states:
You can either directly access the data property, or you can use CakeRequest::data() to read the data array in an error free manner. Any keys that do not exist will return null:

Answer (score 6):

```
 for the GET method 
 $this->request->query['category-name'];

 and POST method 
 $this->request->data
```

> http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-querystring-parameters

Answer (score 3):

You can check if posted a form by using

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {
  print_r($this->data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Post data must be in data to show up in $this->request->data.

Example:

```
// input field
<input type="text" name="data[foo]" value="bar" />

// in your controller
debug($this->request->data);
```

Answer (score 2):

To check if posted a form, please use:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    pr($this->request->data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a specific field of the table can move so:

```
if($this->data["Objetorastreavel"]["id"]){
}
```

It checks only the ID `Objetorestraeval` if you want to pick only one field and not post the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

You should able to access form post data with:

**For CakePHP 2.x**

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    pr($this->request->data);
}
```

**For CakePHP 3.4.x**

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    pr($this->request->getData());
}
```

[Documentation for CakePHP 3](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#request-body-data)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following to retrieve post/get data in CakePHP

**For post data:**
`$this->request->data;`

**For get data:**
`$this->request->query;`